# Writing a correlation equation into R

Tags: r, correlation, equation

I am trying to turn this [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMard.jpg) into r-code to apply to a dataset. I made an example data set:

```
a <- c(4, 6, 2, 5)
b <- c(8, 1, 3, 7)
c <- c(6, 3, 1, 3)
d <- c(7, 5, 7, 5)

data <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)
data
```

Tried to use the scale() function to standardize it.

```
data <- scale(data)
data
```

Then tried to turn it into a matrix to find the determinant.

```
datamatrix <- data.matrix(data)
datamatrix
unlist(determinant(datamatrix))
det(datamatrix)
```

But I have no idea if I am going in the right direction. Is there an easier way to write it in fewer lines? Nevertheless I seem to be stuck.

Comment: Silly me, I was changing the name from "al" to "data" so it is easier to read before posting but missed that one. But yes, it is supposed to be data. I have made the edition.

Comment: That is for the Matthews Correlation Coefficient, which works with binary classifications and would not be applicable to this situation. Unless I am mistaken?

Comment: Does `cor(data)` not provide the desired result? Not sure which one your referenced formula is, but you have the options of `method = c("pearson", 
    "kendall", "spearman")`

Comment: No, it just makes a simple correlation matrix. The equation calculates one value for the correlation of more than two variables.